# Ubuntu 20.10 Ubuntu software

Tags: icons

Tried to update from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 but failed due to i/o error. Installed 20.10 from scratch, clicked on the Ubuntu software icon, spins and nothing comes up. Any solution?

Comment: What's the actual error you're seeing?  "I/O Error" without specific information with it could mean almost any type of error message.  If i'ts a disk related I/O error thoug hthen you have a bigger problem.

Comment: I reinstalled the ubuntu 20.10 from a ubs device, overwrote the previous installation. Installed (I'm assuming) correctly, my issue is the Ubuntu software icon, doesn't appear to work. Tries to load but nothing comes up

Comment: Best bet(my opinion) is to install another software store, can google for a brunch, like app grid myself.  Would do what @Thomas Ward suggested and check further into the I/O error.

Comment: I've done a fsck on disk and corrected issues when it failed during the upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10. Subsequently did an install of 20.10 from ubs device.